# Can you build a station using closed loop production?

Tags: x4-foundations

I changed the preferred production method on the build plan for a station to `Closed Loop`, added a pair of Argon pulse turrets and an Argon shield generator. When I confirmed the changes the parts needed for construction included turret components and other miscellaneous parts, just like it was `Universal` production. How can I arm a station using closed loop production?